# Can I make another user close an Excel file from my computer?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an Excel file that a lot of people can access.

Every morning I run a VBA query on it to update some data.

The problem is that there is another person currently on this sheet and when I try to run my macro, at the very end I get a message of "We cannot merge your changes with the changes of another user". Usually I would fix this by asking the other person to exit the file while I run this macro, the problem is that the other person works in another country and I cannot ask him to exit the file for the next 7 hours which is when his shift starts, but also I need to run my macro now as I need the updated data.

Is there a way, either with Excel options or with a VBA code that I can make him exit this file from my computer so I can run my code?

Comment: It sounds as if you should seriously start considering moving to another workflow where data is either backed by a true database (for example a Power BI dataset) that can be updated independently of any sheets, and/or having people open sheets that are automatically generated from a template as necessary, for example with Power Automate. In either case you would be freed from the restriction that things can only be updated if nobody happens to be using them, which is only going to become more onerous moving forward.

Comment: Surely he should save & close the file at shift end?

Comment: The answer to your original question is almost certainly going to be "no", unless the file is being hosted on your own machine, in which case you could at least close shared handles to it with various tools (like Process Explorer, but there are probably tools for the less technically minded as well). In theory that could then be done with VBA code as well, but that would be far from pretty, and the work is probably better spent changing the approach entirely.

Comment: Try having a look at this https://superuser.com/questions/643916/remotely-close-open-shared-files